# Is it necessary for a WCAG compliance and accessibility review to be familiar with the website's right-to-left language?

Tags: accessibility, right-to-left, wcag, wcag2.0

I want to contract a WCAG compliance and accessibility review on a Persian-language website. Several consultants indicate that they have no experience with right-to-left languages. They also tell me that this isn't necessary to conduct a thorough accessibility review of a right-to-left, Persian-language website.

One consultant has responded, saying that he is not comfortable to do this review. He believes he might miss important accessibility concerns because of the language barrier.

I'm not familiar enough with WCAG to know if experience with right-to-left languages in general, and Persian in particular, is an impediment to conducting a thorough accessibility review. Nor do I seem to be able to find a WCAG and accessibility professional that can help me audit a right-to-left, Persian-language website.

Can anybody shed light on the necessity for experience with Persian and/or right-to-left languages in order to do a thoroughgoing WCAG compliance and accessibility review?

Comment: It *could* be done without knowing the language but would take longer to do so.  Ideally, the tester knows the language, whether it's RTL or LTR.  As noted by @alejandro, there are several guidelines that talk about labels being descriptive. If the tester can't read the language, how do they know if the label is descriptive? Google translate might help and if you can't find anyone that knows the language, that might be the best you can do. Feel free to contact me about doing this work. Contact info in my profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is essential to understand the website's language to do a good review. Of course, the best option is that the accessibility consultant understands the language. Perhaps, including a professional translator in the project could be a possible solution if you can't find any accessibility consultants familiar with Persian.

Some WCAG criteria that the consultant needs to understand the language to evaluate them:

- 1.1.1 Non-text content: ALT texts need to be evaluated
- All criteria under the 1.2 principle (audio, subtitles, etc.)
- 2.4.4 Link Purpose (In Context): the purpose of the link can be determined
- 2.4.6 Headings and Labels: evaluates that headings and labels describe the topic or purpose
- Other criteria like 1.3.3 Sensory Characteristics that evaluates that sensory characteristics are not being used as instructions for understanding or operating content

Regarding what you ask about reading order it is also very important. As in WCAG reading order is mentioned in the criteria and techniques. For example, 2.4.3: Focus Order takes into account the reading order.

Comment: Good to have the appropriate WCAG in your answer. I might be tempted include Info an Relationships. Just to add: if for some reason the auditor/reviewer is not able to understand a given language, this constraint can be included in the conformance report for the above-mentioned success criteria (preferably with a pledge to address the shortcoming within a given timeframe). Transparency is more important than perfection.